# How to do not remove folder if there is a csv file in any of its subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clear directories but I want to leave folders that have csv files inside. I tried to use this command:

`Remove-Item -Path "$Using:MyPath" -Exclude "*.csv", "*.end" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop`

But it will not work with the structure below. If a csv file is inside
Sub2Folder `Remove-Item` will remove SubFolder with all it's contents and I will lose my csv files. Is there a way to avoid this situation and not to delete folders if any of it's subfolders has a csv file inside?

MainFolder

- SubFolder
- - Sub2Folder
- - - somefile.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small script which does exaclty this. Ask me if you need more help ;)

```
$subfolders = Get-Childitem "$Using:MyPath\*" -Directory
#Get all folders
#foreach folder in the folders
foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) { 
    if (!(Get-Childitem $subfolder.FullName -Recurse -Filter "*.csv")){ #If subfolder empty
        Remove-Item $subfolder.FullName -Force -Recurse #Remove this folder
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Grzegorz Ochlik I did some changes to the script. (-Directory switch and no measure-object

If I helped you, please mark this post as the answer :D

Comment: Don't need to do where-object. Get-ChildItem has -Directory switch.
If you'll do -Recurse -Directory, you'll get all folders, no need to iterate, as it takes longer time and there are more calculations included by you.

You don't have to do measure-object. Boolean conditional of Get-ChildItem will be false if there is nothing in folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
Get-ChildItem "$Using:MyPath" -Exclude "*.csv","*.end" -Recurse -File | Foreach {Remove-Item $_.Fullname}
```

This will list All files except the wildcarded files and remove them.

Comment: he wants to delete the folder though

Comment: So...@Nicicalu you mean  move all files to root directory?

Comment: I think he wants to delete the folder where no csv files are in. like in my answer.